# Функция requests.get() не принимает аргумент proxies. Модуль requests. Python

Tags: python, requests, proxy

Пишу парсер и мне нужно использовать прокси. Указываю url и headers, но также мне нужно указать аргумент proxies, но почему-то его просто нету. PyCharm его не выводит в подсказках и такое чувство, что такой аргумент просто убрали с функции.
Вот код:

```
    try:
        response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers, proxies)
        if response.status_code in [430, 503]:
            raise Exception
        logger.info(f"[+] {url} {response.status_code}")
    except Exception as ex:
```

Аргумент proxies не дописан, так как интерпретатор говорит, что такого аргумента не существует.

Comment: А вы попробуйте дописать. вдруг он там аргументы принимает как `**kv` и тогда ваш редактор не догадается какие там имена у них

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Открываем [документацию](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies) и смотрим, что прокси передается именованным аргументом.

```
import requests

proxies = {
  'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:3128',
  'https': 'http://10.10.1.10:1080',
}

requests.get('http://example.org', proxies=proxies)
```

В вашем случае:

```
response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
```